# SyntaxNet - Can I get count of a given bigram/trigram from syntaxnet?

Tags: syntaxnet

I need to get the frequency of occurence of a given bigram or trigram - is this possible with syntaxnet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but why would you use SyntaxNet for that when you can do the same with something much less complex like [CWB](http://cwb.sourceforge.net) or NLTK.

Comment: Iam already using SyntaxNet for my grammar tool and do not want to plugin one more